# $a,b,c$ are in geometric progression; $a^p=b^q=c^r$; relation between $p,q,r$

Tags: arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

> $a,b$ and $c$ are in geometric progression with $a^p=b^q=c^r$. What is the relation between $p,q$ and $r$?

I have three options:

1. $p,q,r$ are in geometric progression
2. $p,q,r$ are in arithmetic progression
3. $1/p,1/q,1/r$ are in arithmetic progression

Any help with how to find out the solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$a^p=b^q=c^r=k\\
\Rightarrow a=k^{\frac 1p}, b=k^{\frac 1q}, c=k^{\frac 1r}$$
For $a,b,c$ to be in a GP, 
$$
\frac ba=\frac cb\\
k^{\frac 1q-\frac 1p}=k^{\frac 1r-\frac 1q}\\
\frac 1q-\frac 1p=\frac 1r-\frac 1q$$
i.e. $\frac 1p, \frac 1q, \frac 1r$ 
are in AP.

Answer (score 0):

if $a,b,c$ in a GP, then we have
$$c:b=b:a$$ with $$a=t^{1/p},b=t^{1/q},c=t^{1/r}$$ we get
$$t^{1/r-1/q}=t^{1/q-1/p}$$ comparing the exponents we have
$$\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{p}=\frac{1}{2q}$$
if $$p,q,r$$ in a AP then we have $$r+p=2q$$
for the last question we have $$\frac{2}{q}=\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{p}$$

Comment: should we use the condition $$a^p=b^q=c^r$$ again?